# DoubleClick Native Template Ads using Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, double-click, double-click-advertising

We are trying to load DoubleClick Native Template Ads
using the Google.MobileAds for iOS in Xamarin.
We load the Native Ad using the following code:

```
AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader(adUnitId, this, new NSObject[]{ AdLoaderType.NativeCustomTemplate }, new AdLoaderOptions[] { });
adLoader.Delegate = new MyCustomNativeCustomTemplateAdLoaderDelegate(new string[] { templateId }, holderUI, onAdLoaded, onAdFailed);
adLoader.LoadRequest(Google.MobileAds.DoubleClick.Request.GetDefaultRequest());
```

In most cases, ads are successfully rendered but sometimes they are not rendered at all without calling to any of the following callbacks (DidFailToReceiveAd, DidReceiveNativeCustomTemplateAd) and there is a blank white space instead of an ad. If we click on the blank space it shows a popup saying :Invalid URI: The URI is empty. When we click the popup's ok button then the ad is successfully rendered. Anyone knows what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone out there who might have the same issue, here's the answer:

The code above was called every time in UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) method.
Now, we put the first 2 lines of code in UITableViewCell constructor and from GetCell we call only the last line.